# Receiving POST with Rack ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a simple ruby server something like :

```
app = Proc.new do |env| 
  puts 'am I receiving anything ? ' 
  req = Rack::Request.new(env).params 
  puts "if yes any parameters ? : #{req.inspect}" 
end 

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => 4001, :threaded => true)
```

How am I supposed to receive POST request with the parameters , I'm sending some JSON object using post but I can see nothing like i'm receiving nothing when I send POST to localhost:4001 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not returning a response. Your response is empty so you won't see anything. You can test this through cURL:

```
$ curl -F 'foo=bar' localhost:4001
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Response from within app:

```
am I receiving anything ? 
if yes any parameters ? : {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

Try returning something:

```
app = Proc.new do |env|
  puts 'am I receiving anything ? '
  req = Rack::Request.new(env).params
  puts "if yes any parameters ? : #{req.inspect}"
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['Some body']]
end
```

Comment: so it is i can receive both GET and POST with the same Rack::Request.new(env).params ? even if it was like JSON object sent with POST ? or any other serialization type ?

Comment: Yes. Rack::Request does not care what type of request method was used. That's up to the user to add conditions for